# Animating like balloon bursting using javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like make a image burst to pieces, this animation should continue infinetly. Pls advice on how to proceed with this? Is it possible to use the jquery animate function to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,
 http://jsfiddle.net/Dripple/AGGrv/. 
This makes a fine animation of bursting a balloon.

```
$("#bubble1").click(function() {
    $("#bubble1").stop(true, false);
    $(this).hide("explode", {
        pieces: 50
    }, 250);
});

function animate1() {
    $("#bubble1").animate({
        "-moz-border-radius": "110px/100px",
        "-webkit-border-radius": "110px 100px",
        "border-radius": "110px/100px",
        height: '100px',
        width: '110px',
        top: '240px'
    }, 1500, animate2());
}

function animate2() {
    $("#bubble1").animate({
        "-moz-border-radius": "100px/110px",
        "-webkit-border-radius": "100px 110px",
        "border-radius": "100px/110px",
        height: '110px',
        width: '100px',
        top: '235px'
    }, 1500, function() {
        $('#bubble1').trigger('mouseover');
    });
}

$("#bubble1").mouseover(function() {
    animate1();
});

$("#bubble1").mouseout(function() {
    $("#bubble1").stop(true, false);
});
```